# Extract names of the levels of a factor

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, bigdata

I'm trying to read a huge matrix (2.8gb) in R, thus, so far, the best I have found is

```
 require(data.table)

 DT<-fread("bigmatrix.csv")
```

of which I know almost nothing!

After this I'm able to tell you that this matrix has 3 columns and 50 milion rows.

Each row is of the type

```
             object1                       object 2           distance
 1: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI           Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI 0.0000000
 2: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI         Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GXANA 0.2195843  
 3: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.KHOEKHOEGOWAB 0.6749363
 4: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI          Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.KHWE 0.6089206
 5: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI        Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.KORANA 0.7163111
 6: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI         Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.KWADI 0.8017179
```

So it's comparing distances of 2 objects pairwise for approximately 6900 objects

Now comes my problem:

I want to excract the pairwise comparison of just 41 objects. However I don't know how the guy who gave me this dataset has called these 41 objects!!

So my solution would be to find the levels of DT$object1, write them in a file and then scan them to find the 41 I need, how can I do it?

I tried

```
foo<-factor(DT$object1)
```

So when I call

```
foo

....

6895 Levels: AA.BEJA.BEJA AA.BEJA.BEJA_2 AA.BERBER.AWJILAH ... Zun.ZUNI.ZUNI
```

but

```
foo$Levels
```

gives me an error!

I'm sure there is a smarter way than what I would do in C++ (i.e. loop over each row, insert the name of Object 1 in a vector of strings only if it's not present yet), but how do I do it?

---

**EDIT:** Now another question arose:

I have identified the 41 objects that I need, how do I exctract from the data.table the rows that are relevant to me?

I can store the names of the objects in a data frame or a vector

Comment: read.table() is used to import tab delimited data files in R. You must read the basics before your start playing with the data.To extract 41 rows from the data, you need to subset the data. Read more about subsetting at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Comment: To get the unique values, you can do `unique(DT$object1)`. If you want them sorted, you can do `sort(unique(DT$object1))`.

Answer (score 7):

try:
`levels(as.factor(DT$object1))`